# Create an entity by summarizing data in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, python-3.6, postgresql-9.6

I'm working with an existing schema about combat data in a video game, because I have to work with data generated by an external program. This schema isn't technically compatible with how I want to organize the data, but it mostly works.

One problem that comes up 3 times (so far) is providing the user with a big table of data to browse/search through to start sifting through the data that's available. So, I decided to have a single generic way of generating a data table, and handling AJAX requests for more data to that table.

The problem is that one of these cases is basically retrieving data straight from a table, while another is actually retrieving summarized data from a table. For example, the schema defines a 'Combatant', or a participant in a combat, but I want the system to expose a concept of a 'Character', or a thing that exists and participates in many combats. So, a `Character` would be a `Combatant` in multiple, different `Encounter`s.

There's basically two ways I can create the idea of a Character from the database. I can either use a view, or I can have my ORM (SQLAlchemy) create the required query from scratch every time. View support is possible in SQLAlchemy via some [possible extensions](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/Views), but because I'm summarizing, I lose the primary key, and therefore I can't create an ORM class representing the view. Supposedly, you can force a column to be a primary key, but that didn't work for me (seemed to do nothing). If I try to use the query from scratch, my current way of generating a generic table doesn't work for want of being able to inspect(...) a query result.

So, I have two questions, and [a MCVE](http://pastebin.com/WmNLFzkt) for the query-from-scratch approach:

1. Am I taking an approach to this problem known to be bad?
2. Is there a way to avoid using inspect(...) that lets me use arbitrary strings to get values from a query result object?

Some notes about the MCVE:

- I've stripped down the number of ORM objects, the columns in each, and the config information in the column lists. The column lists are ugly in their original form.
- Where the double-nested `for` loops are in the MCVE, there's a templating system in my actual code. Web server, generating HTML, all the usual fun has been stripped out to focus on SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up solving this by using [this code for Materialized Views](https://github.com/jeffwidman/sqlalchemy-postgresql-materialized-views). So, all the aggregation is done by the DB, and SQLAlchemy just treats the view as another selectable.